# Add certain words to a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am using this code to read the line number 2 from files has the same name and included in folders (the name of those folders included in list.txt):

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/au/cl/tr/129/
inlist=/1/2/3
g=/1/5/file.txt

for i in $(cat $inlist/list.txt); do
 echo ${i}
 sed '2q;d' ${in}/${i}/${g};
 done > newfile.txt
```

the output of this code (the content of newfile.txt) is as the following:

```
 folder 1  
 a 
 folder 2
 b
 folder 3
 c
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

a, b, c are the value of the second line in the files

how can I add "i" which is the name of the folder (included in list.txt) to the output of the code so I will have the value in line 2 and the name of the folder in the same row as the following

```
 folder1 (a) 
 folder2 (b)
 folder3 (c)
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: show us your expected output

Comment: `a b c` is in 2nd line in your list.txt??

Comment: your question is not clear, give us expected in put and expected output

Comment: no in list.txt I have the folders names and inside every folder I have on file. This file has the same name in all the folders. a b c are the values of the second line in those files i e a from the first file b from the second file ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to do it in `sed`, Perl can help. It stores the name of the file it's reading from in the special variable `$ARGV` and the line number in the special variable `$.`, so this should work:

```
...
for i in $(cat $inlist/list.txt); do
    perl -nle 'print "$ARGV ($_)" and last if ($.==2)' "${in}/${i}/${g}"
done
```

To grab multiple lines:

```
...
for i in $(cat $inlist/list.txt); do
    perl -nle '
        BEGIN{
            @lines = (2,3,5);
            print "$ARGV: "
        }
        print "Line $.: $_" if grep { $. == $_ } @lines;
        last if $. == $lines[-1];
    ' "${in}/${i}/${g}"
done
```

The above will print lines 2, 3 and 5. This assumes that the last entry in the array `@lines` is the very last line you want printed.

Comment: Thanks this is great! Kindly, If i want perl to read two line for example 2 and 5 how can I do it?

Comment: @MJA I can't see a non-convoluted way of doing this in Perl right now. Honestly, I believe `sed` can do a better job in this case. If you need to grab more than one-line, I'd go with the `sed` solution.

Comment: how can I do it in sed

Comment: @MJA Maybe couple [Yash's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165983/26909) with something like: `sed -n '2p;3p;5{p;q}' file` to print lines 2, 3 and 5.

Comment: @MJA You bet. Glad I could help.

Comment: @MJA I added a way to do it in Perl.

Comment: Fantastic!! thanks a lot. But you know this code is adding the path as the number of lines i.e if you want to read line 25. it is adding 25 path before the value of the line 25?

Comment: @MJA My bad. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
in=/au/cl/tr/129/
inlist=/1/2/3
g=/1/5/file.txt

for i in $(cat $inlist/list.txt); do
 echo -n "$i ("
 sed '2q;d' ${in}/${i}/${g};
 echo ")"
done > newfile.txt
```

-n switch tell echo not to print newline character.
Ref: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/echo

Comment: Thank you! it works. Do you know any other ways to do it?